# distribution of income over time based on rule set

Tags: sql-server, algorithm

Not sure if I was able to properly describe the title of my question but I haven't done anything this complex in T-Sql. Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

After several queries and table building, I got the data (below) in a temp table which probably will become a permanent table.
The part I need help with is, Need to create another table to report part of the sale from the data below.

```
Table 1
LOC#    ITEM        sale_total  FiscalYear  FiscalPrd   TYPE    O_R DESC        LFT_EXP METHOD  PRD_MO  AG_PCNT PLAN_ID YEARS   STATUS
33      17879       12203.57    2017        3           A       O   Plan A      L       W       120     100.00  6       10      N
33      17903       579.97      2017        3           A       O   Plan A      L       W       120     100.00  6       10      N
33      18870       799.60      2017        3           A       O   Plan A      L       W       120     100.00  6       10      N
33      19739       319.95      2017        3           A       B   Plan C      E       F       36      100.00  8       3       N
33      21585       559.96      2017        3           B       O   Plan B      E       N       0       100.00  10      0       N
```

A percentage of the sale_total from table above needs to be distributed based on the table below (I can also include the YR01-YR10 columns in the table above if it make things simpler).

```
Table 2
PLAN_ID EFDATE      MONTHS  METHOD  EPERCENT    YR01    YR02    YR03    YR04    YR05    YR06    YR07    YR08    YR09    YR10
6       2007-08-01  120     W       100.00      40.00   20.00   11.00   8.00    6.00    5.00    4.00    3.00    2.00    1.00
8       2012-11-12  36      F       100.00      33.00   33.00   34.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
10      2015-10-01  0       N       100.00      0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

So my end result would look like below for LOC#33 and item 18870: (So the calculation is based on the plan. For this specific example, item 18870 falls under plan 6 (table 1). Table 2 has the distribution of all plans. We can see it spreads over 120 months and YR01-YR10 has the yearly percent distribution. Now from the sales number for 18870 from table 1, 799.60, distribution math for year 1 is (799.60 x 0.4) / 12 = 26.65. Same method follows up to year 10 for this plan and up to year 3 for plan 8. For the 10 year plan, it will create 120 input records. 1 for each month for each item, location)

```
LOC#    ITEM    FiscalYear  FiscalPrd   SALES   
33      18870   2017        4           26.65
33      18870   2017        5           26.85
33      18870   2017        6           26.85
.............................................
.............................................
33      18870   2017        11          26.85
33      18870   2017        12          26.85
33      18870   2018        1           13.33
33      18870   2018        2           13.33
.............................................
.............................................
33      18870   2018        11          13.33
33      18870   2018        12          13.33
.............................................
.............................................
33      18870   2027        2           0.67
33      18870   2027        3           0.67
```

It will distribute that income over 120 months at the percentage dictated by the table 2 for planID 6. for planID 8, it will do the same math over 36 months.
The percentages can change over time and a user will manage the plans. There are other locations and the first table will include all location for the current fiscal period and all items (3 max as shows in Table 2). I created a status columns so I can mark if once the data is processed.

When comes the next fiscal period sales, the program will update the above result set sales numbers to include new sales. It will be run once a month to generate the above result.

Would greatly appreciate some direction as I got up to this point and not sure how to approach from here.

Thanks a bunch.

@ZLK I saved the first run in a temp table, then added the following rows

```
(33, 17879, 10000.00, 2017, 4, 6, 10),
(33, 17903, 500.00, 2017, 4, 6, 10),
(33, 18870, 800.00, 2017, 4, 6, 10),
(33, 19739, 300.00, 2017, 4, 8, 3),
(33, 21585, 500.00, 2017, 4, 10, 0);
```

This the save first set of item, location with different sales number in fiscal period 4. the first set was inserted into a table #finalDist, the second uses the following query to insert and update.

```
begin tran
if exists (select * FROM #finalDist AGE
                INNER JOIN #dist PrdAg on PrdAg.Loc = AGE.Loc 
                    and PrdAg.Item = AGE.Item 
                    and PrdAg.FiscalYear = AGE.FiscalYear 
                    and PrdAg.FiscalPrd = AGE.FiscalPrd)
begin
    UPDATE AGE 
        SET AGE.SALES = AGE.SALES + PrdAg.SALES 
    FROM #finalDist AGE
    INNER JOIN #dist PrdAg on PrdAg.Loc = AGE.Loc 
            and PrdAg.Item = AGE.Item 
            and PrdAg.FiscalYear = AGE.FiscalYear 
            and PrdAg.FiscalPrd = AGE.FiscalPrd
end
else
begin
    INSERT INTO #finalDist (Loc, Item, FiscalYear, FiscalPrd, SALES) 
    SELECT Loc, Item, FiscalYear, FiscalPrd, SALES from #dist PrdAg

        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT AGE.Item FROM #finalDist AGE WHERE PrdAg.Loc = AGE.Loc 
                                                                    and PrdAg.Item = AGE.Item 
                                                                    and PrdAg.FiscalYear = AGE.FISCALYear
                                                                    and PrdAg.FiscalPrd = AGE.FiscalPrd)
end
commit tran
```

I realize I can't do if else as I need to do both insert and update. It will update everything except the fiscal period 3, then it will insert four rows for this case

```
Loc Item    FiscalYear  FiscalPrd   SALES
33  18870   2027           4       0.66666666666
33  19739   2020           4       8.50000000000
33  17903   2027           4       0.41666666666
33  17879   2027           4       8.33333333333
```

update look like this

```
33  17879   2017           4       406.78566666666 -- this row wasn't updated
33  17879   2017           5       740.11899999999
```

Comment: Where do the `SALES` numbers come from? e.g. How does 26.85 divide into any of the other numbers?

Comment: Sorry about not being clear and I messed up on the calculation as I changed the percentage bit didn't change the resulting numbers. Fixed the errors. 
So the calculation is based on the plan. For this specific example, item 18870 falls under plan 6 (table 1). Table 2 has the distribution of all plans. We can see it spreads over 120  months and YR01-YR10 has the yearly percent distribution.
Now from the sales number for 18870 from table 1, 799.60, distribution math for year 1 is (799.60 x 0.4) / 12 = 26.65. Same method follows up to year 10 for this plan and up to year 3 for plan 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do it is like this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Loc INT, Item INT, Sales_Total DECIMAL(10, 2), FiscalYear INT, FiscalPrd INT, Plan_ID INT, YEARS INT);

INSERT @T (Loc, Item, Sales_Total, FiscalYear, FiscalPrd, Plan_ID, YEARS) VALUES
(33, 17879, 12203.57, 2017, 3, 6, 10),
(33, 17903, 579.97, 2017, 3, 6, 10),
(33, 18870, 799.60, 2017, 3, 6, 10),
(33, 19739, 319.95, 2017, 3, 8, 3),
(33, 21585, 559.96, 2017, 3, 10, 0);

DECLARE @T2 TABLE (PLAN_ID INT, YR01 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR02 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR03 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR04 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR05 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR06 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR07 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR08 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR09 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR10 DECIMAL(4, 2));

INSERT @T2 (PLAN_ID, YR01, YR02, YR03, YR04, YR05, YR06, YR07, YR08, YR09, YR10) VALUES
(6, 40.00, 20.00, 11.00, 8.00, 6.00, 5.00, 4.00, 3.00, 2.00, 1.00),
(8, 33.00, 33.00, 34.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00),
(10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00);

WITH CTE(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS A(B)),
    CTE2(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM CTE AS A CROSS JOIN CTE) -- Numbers 1-121
SELECT T.Loc, 
       T.Item,
       FiscalYear = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, CTE2.N, DATEFROMPARTS(T.FiscalYear, T.FiscalPrd, 1))),
       FiscalPrd = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, CTE2.N, DATEFROMPARTS(T.FiscalYear, T.FiscalPrd, 1))),
       SALES = T.Sales_Total * C.Vals / 100 / 12
FROM @T AS T
JOIN CTE2
    ON CTE2.N <= T.YEARS * 12 
JOIN 
(
    SELECT T.PLAN_ID, C.Y, C.Vals
    FROM @T2 AS T
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1, YR01), (2, YR02), (3, YR03), (4, YR04), (5, YR05), (6, YR06), (7, YR07), (8, YR08), (9, YR09), (10, YR10)) AS C(Y, Vals) -- Unpivot
) AS C
    ON C.PLAN_ID = T.PLAN_ID
    AND C.Y = (CTE2.N + 11) / 12
ORDER BY T.Loc, T.Item, CTE2.N;
```

Essentially you want to get a list of numbers (up to 120 here but if there's more than 10 years, you would need more) and cross join it to your table. Then unpivot the values in table2 and link them to the numbers table in (grouping them by years).

**EDIT:**

Taking into account that values can change and assuming the end date is still the same and doesn't increase, this is what I believe you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Loc INT, Item INT, Sales_Total DECIMAL(10, 2), FiscalYear INT, FiscalPrd INT, Plan_ID INT, YEARS INT);

INSERT @T (Loc, Item, Sales_Total, FiscalYear, FiscalPrd, Plan_ID, YEARS) VALUES
(33, 17879, 12203.57, 2017, 3, 6, 10),
(33, 17903, 579.97, 2017, 3, 6, 10),
(33, 18870, 799.60, 2017, 3, 6, 10),
(33, 19739, 319.95, 2017, 3, 8, 3),
(33, 21585, 559.96, 2017, 3, 10, 0),
(33, 17879, 10000.00, 2017, 4, 6, 10),
(33, 17903, 500.00, 2017, 4, 6, 10),
(33, 21585, 500.00, 2017, 4, 10, 0),
(33, 17879, 5000.00, 2017, 5, 6, 10),
(33, 17879, 6900.00, 2017, 7, 6, 10);

DECLARE @T2 TABLE (PLAN_ID INT, YR01 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR02 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR03 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR04 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR05 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR06 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR07 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR08 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR09 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR10 DECIMAL(4, 2));

INSERT @T2 (PLAN_ID, YR01, YR02, YR03, YR04, YR05, YR06, YR07, YR08, YR09, YR10) VALUES
(6, 40.00, 20.00, 11.00, 8.00, 6.00, 5.00, 4.00, 3.00, 2.00, 1.00),
(8, 33.00, 33.00, 34.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00),
(10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00);

WITH CTE(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS A(B)),
    CTE2(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 FROM CTE AS A CROSS JOIN CTE) -- Numbers 0-120

SELECT T.Loc, 
       T.Item,
       FiscalYear = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, CTE2.N, T.FirstDate)),
       FiscalPrd = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, CTE2.N, T.FirstDate)),
       SALES = T.TotalToDate * C.Vals / 100 / 12
FROM
(
    SELECT T.Loc,
           T.Item,
           T.YEARS,
           T.Plan_ID,
           C.TotalToDate,
           FirstDate = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CAST(MIN(FiscalYear) OVER (PARTITION BY Loc, Item) AS CHAR(4)) + '-' +
                       CAST(MIN(FiscalPrd) OVER (PARTITION BY Loc, Item) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-01') AS DATE),
           CurrentDate = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CAST(FiscalYear AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(FiscalPrd AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-01') AS DATE),
           C2.NextDate
    FROM @T AS T
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT SUM(Sales_Total) 
        FROM @T 
        WHERE Loc = T.Loc
        AND Item = T.Item
        AND FiscalYear * 12 + FiscalPrd <= T.FiscalYear * 12 + T.FiscalPrd
    ) AS C(TotalToDate)
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CAST(MIN(FiscalYear) AS CHAR(4)) + '-' +
               CAST(MIN(FiscalPrd) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-01') AS DATE)
        FROM @T
        WHERE Loc = T.Loc
        AND Item = T.Item
        AND FiscalYear * 12 + FiscalPrd > T.FiscalYear * 12 + T.FiscalPrd
    ) AS C2(NextDate)
) AS T
JOIN CTE2
    ON CTE2.N <= T.YEARS * 12 - 1
    AND CTE2.N >= DATEDIFF(MONTH, T.FirstDate, T.CurrentDate)
    AND DATEADD(MONTH, CTE2.N, T.FirstDate) < COALESCE(T.NextDate, DATEADD(MONTH, T.YEARS * 12, T.FirstDate))
JOIN 
(
    SELECT T.PLAN_ID, C.Y, C.Vals
    FROM @T2 AS T
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1, YR01), (2, YR02), (3, YR03), (4, YR04), (5, YR05), (6, YR06), (7, YR07), (8, YR08), (9, YR09), (10, YR10)) AS C(Y, Vals) -- Unpivot
) AS C
    ON C.PLAN_ID = T.PLAN_ID
    AND C.Y = (CTE2.N + 12) / 12
ORDER BY T.Loc, T.Item, CTE2.N;
```

**SECOND EDIT (Modified to have the start date be the month declared, e.g. March 2017 means the plan starts in March 2017 instead of April 2017. The only difference is adjusting the row_number joins):**

```
/*
    @PlanTable: A static table for plans.
*/

DECLARE @PlanTable TABLE (PLAN_ID INT, YR01 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR02 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR03 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR04 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR05 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR06 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR07 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR08 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR09 DECIMAL(4, 2), YR10 DECIMAL(4, 2));
INSERT @PlanTable (PLAN_ID, YR01, YR02, YR03, YR04, YR05, YR06, YR07, YR08, YR09, YR10) VALUES
(6, 40.00, 20.00, 11.00, 8.00, 6.00, 5.00, 4.00, 3.00, 2.00, 1.00),
(8, 33.00, 33.00, 34.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00),
(10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00);   

/* 
    @RecordsToInsert: The values you're inserting into your final table. Starting with FiscalYear 2017 and FiscalPrd 3 as an example.
*/

DECLARE @RecordsToInsert TABLE (Loc INT, Item INT, Sales_Total DECIMAL(10, 2), FiscalYear INT, FiscalPrd INT, Plan_ID INT, YEARS INT);
INSERT @RecordsToInsert (Loc, Item, Sales_Total, FiscalYear, FiscalPrd, Plan_ID, YEARS) VALUES
(33, 17879, 12203.57, 2017, 3, 6, 10),
(33, 17903, 579.97, 2017, 3, 6, 10),
(33, 18870, 799.60, 2017, 3, 6, 10),
(33, 19739, 319.95, 2017, 3, 8, 3),
(33, 21585, 559.96, 2017, 3, 10, 0);

/*
    @FinalTable: This is the table you're using to insert the data. 
*/

DECLARE @FinalTable TABLE (Loc INT, Item INT, FiscalYear INT, FiscalPrd INT, SALES DECIMAL(10, 2));

/*
    Start by inserting the first lot of information into the final table.
*/

WITH CTE(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS A(B)),
    CTE2(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 FROM CTE AS A CROSS JOIN CTE) -- Numbers 0-120
INSERT @FinalTable (Loc, Item, FiscalYear, FiscalPrd, SALES)
SELECT T.Loc, 
       T.Item,
       FiscalYear = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, CTE2.N, CAST(T.FiscalYear AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(T.FiscalPrd AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-01')),
       FiscalPrd = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, CTE2.N, CAST(T.FiscalYear AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(T.FiscalPrd AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-01')),
       SALES = T.Sales_Total * C.Vals / 100 / 12
FROM @RecordsToInsert AS T
JOIN CTE2
    ON CTE2.N <= T.YEARS * 12 - 1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT T.PLAN_ID, C.Y, C.Vals
    FROM @PlanTable AS T
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1, YR01), (2, YR02), (3, YR03), (4, YR04), (5, YR05), (6, YR06), (7, YR07), (8, YR08), (9, YR09), (10, YR10)) AS C(Y, Vals) -- Unpivot
) AS C
    ON C.PLAN_ID = T.PLAN_ID
    AND C.Y = CTE2.N / 12 + 1
ORDER BY T.Loc, T.Item, CTE2.N;

/*
    Next we want to insert records for the next FiscalPrd, so we get rid of the last ones and put in FiscalYear 2017, FiscalPrd 4.
*/

DELETE @RecordsToInsert;
INSERT @RecordsToInsert (Loc, Item, Sales_Total, FiscalYear, FiscalPrd, Plan_ID, YEARS) VALUES
(33, 17879, 10000.00, 2017, 4, 6, 10),
(33, 17903, 500.00, 2017, 4, 6, 10),
(33, 18870, 800.00, 2017, 4, 6, 10),
(33, 19739, 300.00, 2017, 4, 8, 3),
(33, 21585, 500.00, 2017, 4, 10, 0);

/*
    Then we update the final table with the new sales total, ignoring periods that were prior to the fiscal year and period being inserted.
*/

UPDATE T
SET SALES = SALES_NEW
FROM (
SELECT FT.Loc,
       FT.Item,
       FT.FiscalYear,
       FT.FiscalPrd,
       FT.SALES,
       SALES_NEW = (SUM(FT.SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY FT.Loc, FT.Item) + R.Sales_Total)  * C.Vals / 100 / COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY FT.Loc, FT.Item, (FT.RN + 11) / 12)
FROM (SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Loc, Item ORDER BY FiscalYear, FiscalPrd) FROM @FinalTable) AS FT
JOIN @RecordsToInsert AS R
    ON R.Loc = FT.Loc
    AND R.Item = FT.Item
    AND R.FiscalYear * 12 + R.FiscalPrd <= FT.FiscalYear * 12 + FT.FiscalPrd
JOIN 
(
    SELECT T.PLAN_ID, C.Y, C.Vals
    FROM @PlanTable AS T
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1, YR01), (2, YR02), (3, YR03), (4, YR04), (5, YR05), (6, YR06), (7, YR07), (8, YR08), (9, YR09), (10, YR10)) AS C(Y, Vals) -- Unpivot
) AS C
    ON C.PLAN_ID = R.PLAN_ID
    AND C.Y = (FT.RN + 11) / 12
) T;

/*
    For the first year, the sales for 2017/5 onwards have changed to (totalsales - firstmonth) * 40% / 11
    For the second years onward, the sales have changed to totalsales * whatever% / 12
    The first month of the first year remains the same.
*/

SELECT Loc, Item, FiscalYear, FiscalPrd, SALES
FROM @FinalTable
ORDER BY Loc, Item, FiscalYear, FiscalPrd;
```

Comment: Wow! This is brilliant! I've started coding this using some crazy method and mine looks so inefficient compared to this. Still trying to figure out your code but how would this work when data comes in for the next period? As I mentioned, I would need to update the sale numbers and keep spreading each period. Maybe I generate this and run an update statement to update a final table where item, year, period matches? Also, this would run on a 2008 R2 and the function DATEFROMPARTS isn't available there but luckily I had access to a 2012 server where I was able to test it.

Comment: I believe I have the later part figured out. Got a replacement for DATEFROMPARTS. Also dumping the result set from the query above to a temp table, then writing to the actual result table (insert or update). Will do some more testing and report. Thanks so much again.

Comment: How would the new data change the numbers? It would help if you edited the OP with an example of what happens in the next month and what the numbers should look like as a result

Comment: Updated the original post. Please let me know what you think or further improvements can be made. Also, need to have an feature to prevent from double entry/update. What I mean is, if a period is already processed, prevent users from re-entering the same period and update the numbers.

Comment: @J.Doe To be clear, the end date is still the same (i.e. it's still 10 years from March 2017 in the example, you've just added to the total in a later month)?

Comment: I edited it with an example of a modified query that I believe gives you what you're looking for. Essentially, it just calculates the start date, total to date and current date of any entry and does basically the same thing as the original query. Check the sample data as well.

Comment: I will only select 1 month at a time. To simplify, if it was distributed over 12 mo instead of 120 and I'm distributing sales for 03/17, I'll run report in April. I'll build table-1 with 3/17 data only. won't include any other month. once run, I will have the spread from 4/17 thru 3/18 (12 months) then I write it to FinalDist table.

Comment: In May, 17, I will build table-1 with 4/17 data only and once I run this program, it will update/insert the numbers in FinalDist table. 04/17 data will remain untouched, 5/17 thru 3/18 data will get updated (sales += AprilSale). and one new row will be added in FinalDist for 4/18 with april-18 sale number. Hope I was able to explain. Now this is for a 12 month plan that's distributed for the same location.

Comment: Also, your updated code isn't running in sql server 2008. The following lines are causing errors: "           FirstDate = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CAST(MIN(FiscalYear) OVER (PARTITION BY Loc, Item ORDER BY FiscalYear) AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(MIN(FiscalPrd) OVER (PARTITION BY Loc, Item ORDER BY FiscalYear, FiscalPrd) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-01') AS DATE)," says incorrect syntax near 'order'. Next error is here "    ) AS C(TotalToDate)" says incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. Thoughts? Also noticed, the new version will address current year. putting in older data (2016) and it ignores that.

Comment: @J.Doe Sorry, removing the `order by` will make it work in 2008. Edited to reflect that. As for the other issue, I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to achieve (it would make more sense to me to have a base table with a record for each month rather than a separate thing for each month that you put into another table), but I'll edit in what I think you're trying to achieve soon.

Comment: @J.Doe I'm still not very clear as to what should happen by adding, say, $10000. e.g. If you start with 12203.57 then add 10,000 for plan 6, does that mean the first year still has 40% of the total minus the first month distributed over 11 months? e.g. (22203.57 [total] - 406.79 [first month]) * 0.4 [percentage] / 11 [months left in first year] = 792.62 for the next 11 months in the first year?

Comment: As another example, let's say I add some ridiculous amount like 1,000,000 in sales at the very end of the year. So you'll need to change your final table starting at 2018, period 3. That means you'd have 400,000 + the original amount in fiscal year 2018, period 3, correct (because 40% would be distributed over a single month)?

Comment: See the part marked **SECOND EDIT** for what I believe you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Is it possible to have a chat session so I can try to explain better? Not sure what time zone you're in but I can be available pretty much anytime you're free. please let me know. And I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: I'm Australian (GMT+10) and I usually only browse stack on breaks at work (which starts in 15 mins, 8am). But I probably won't be available that much today. Saturday or Sunday some time would be fine (some time after around now on either day, e.g. about 24-48 hours from the time of this comment).

Comment: Not sure if you use google chat? you can add me eclipse0211@g****.com. I don't want to bother you over your weekend. We can look into it on Monday.

Comment: not sure if you saw my last message. If I want to start the distribution from the same month/period of the data, i.e. if I have data from March, 17, currently the distribution start from April, 17 and goes on for 120 months or 36 months based on the plan. Instead, if I want to start the distribution from the same month (March, 17), what do I need to change? Please let me know when you're available so I can help explain the other(update and import existing data) part. Thanks.

Comment: @J.Doe Sorry, might have missed the first message. Changing it to start from March instead of April (with the first month being March) just requires tweaking the row_numbers slightly. I'll edit the second example to show what I mean shortly. Also, I'm zlk060506@gmail.com on google chat if needed.

Comment: sent you an email. I'm needing to pivot the result set and display in a calendar format. months/fiscalPeriod as columns and the year as rows. for each plan type and each store. Can you assist please?